# /bin/sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off

Tags: command-line, 11.10, upstart, tty

I'm building a custom image to run on a simulator. the kernel boots fine and everything but generates this warning:

```
/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

and the terminal does not provide full functionality, no `ctrl+c` and so.

I tried to fix that using [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/410472/bin-sh-cant-access-tty-job-control-turned-off-error-when-running-shellcode), so I removed `console` and linked `tty0` (there is no `ttyS0`) to `console`, I then tried to edit `/etc/inittab` file only to find that there is no such file in Ubuntu.

after googling a bit I found that Ubuntu uses `Upstart` instead, which itself uses multiple other files in `/etc/init/`, I'm a newbie so I don't know which of these files should I edit (there is no file for `tty0` only `tty1.conf` to `tty6.conf`). these files have different syntax so even if I knew which file to edit I don't know how to edit it. which file and how should I edit?

also is there a problem that I have `tty0` instead of `ttyS0`?

Comment: At least link to the original site instead of some crap scraper: http://superuser.com/questions/410472/bin-sh-cant-access-tty-job-control-turned-off-error-when-running-shellcode

Comment: edited the question!

Comment: If you want to create a ttyS0, create a file called `/etc/init/ttyS0.conf`, with the contents from http://paste.ubuntu.com/10852195/ (which runs `getty` to start a new TTY). However, you don't know why command is causing this error, so you couldn't use the fix in the other question anyway (since you don't know which command has to run on that TTY).

Comment: 11.10 has been end of life and no longer supported for years.